# Can I visit Saudi Arabia from Dubai on UAE Resident Visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dubai, uae, saudi-arabia

I want to visit Saudi Arabia from Dubai. I have an Indian passport and have a UAE Resident Visa.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone requires visas to visit Saudi Arabia, except citizens of GCC countries. There is no exception for merely being a resident.